# Manage Keys with Puppet for puppet-vcsrepo

Tags: git, bazaar, private-key, puppet

I'm setting up some server configuration in my company and we have some internal repositories that run over ssh through bzr that I need to get. I wanted to use puppet-vcsrepo to pull these in and I saw that it has a way we can use a keyfile to get what we want. What is the best way to go about this?

I'm probably going to make a user account for each of us, but do I have to put my private key into puppet as a file and then transfer it over? How do I manage keys inside of puppet so I can checkout repositories ssh without using username and password?

Here is a link to the information: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo/blob/master/README.BZR.markdown

It says to manage keys with puppet, but I couldn't exactly find what I need to know in order to manage the keys correctly.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I can tell you one thing: private keys are not meant to be copied across PCs, ever. Any solution that proposes copying private keys stinks.

Comment: That's the ONLY and best solution I could find to solve my problem. I have to copy the key into root's home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know much about BZR... will answer as if it was a git/github based question

- If you are github based, use [deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) (readonly access, easily revokable) and not a developer key.
- You can manage the key by copying them in ~/.ssh and configure ssh to use it ?

```
file { '/user/home/.ssh/id_rsa-github-mycompany' :
 ... # access right ....
}
```

vcsrepo { "/path/to/repo":
  ...
  require => File[ '/user/home/.ssh']
}

you may need to tweek also the .ssh/config to use this identify file and modify the host name of the git repository

```
Host github-mycompany-project
HostName github.com
  User git
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-github-mycompany
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Another option use an exec and the [git_ssh_wrapper](https://github.com/martinemde/git-ssh-wrapper) gem instead of vcsrepo ?

Comment: Is there a readonly access for ssh? I guess I can create a git user and change their shell?

Comment: you can keep your dev key (I don't know the role of your server,if it's a ci, it problably have this kind of access rights). For bazaar readonly access found this : http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/admin-guide/security.html ?

Comment: I'll think of another way to do this. In the meantime, thanks for your help.